# Не загружается UBUNTU, сообщает о потере раздела PV, LVM Volume Group Shows "unknown device"

Tags: lvm, fstab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно убунту не грузится вылезает initrafms, сообщает о потере устройства, вопрос в том, как это привязать обратно, через конфиг фстаб?
Очень долго уже ломаю голову,прошу помощи